# Добавление пользовательского поля в битрикс API

Tags: php, битрикс, битрикс24

моя цель - добавить контакт с сайта с помощью формы обратной связи
Вот файл - обработчик

```
<?php
$from = '108';
$_POST["name"] = 'test';
$_POST["phone"] = '12312312312321';
$queryUrl = 'https://вебхук';
$queryData = http_build_query(array(
    'fields' => array(
       'UF_CRM_1685972138312' => $from,
        'NAME' => $_POST["name"],
         'SOURCE_ID' => "WEB",
        'PHONE' => Array(
          "n0" =>  Array(
               "VALUE" => str_replace(" ","",$_POST["phone"]),
               "VALUE_TYPE" => "WORK",
           ))
    ),
    'params' => array("REGISTER_SONET_EVENT" => "Y")
)); 
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => $queryUrl,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $queryData,
));
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

?>
```

Суть проблемы в том, что я не могу передать значение пользовательского поля. Поле в самом битриксе текстовое и называется "база", оно имеет пул значений, нужное мне имеет название "База Антона Инстаграм" если смотреть через запрос crm.contact.get?id=, то нужное мне поле называется UF_CRM_1685972138312 и нужное значение "108". Вот как это выглядит в запросе

```
"UF_CRM_1685972138312":"108"
```

При выполнении вышеизложенного кода контакт добавляется, но не добавляется нужное мне поле, оно остается пустым
Если смотреть через запрос  contact.fields, то поле выглядит следующим образом

```
{"ID":"108","VALUE":"\u0411\u0430\u0437\u0430 \u0410\u043d\u0442\u043e\u043d\u0430 \u0418\u043d\u0441\u0442\u0430\u0433\u0440\u0430\u043c"}],"title":"UF_CRM_1685972138312",
```

Также пробовал через массив

```
'UF_CRM_1685972138312' => Array(
                 Array(
               "ID" => $from,
               "VALUE" => "\u0411\u0430\u0437\u0430 \u0410\u043d\u0442\u043e\u043d\u0430 \u0418\u043d\u0441\u0442\u0430\u0433\u0440\u0430\u043c",
           )),
```

тоже не работает, Value в utf8 тоже не дает результата.
Может кто подсказать что я делаю не так?

Comment: Знает кто в чем дело?